# How can I show a div whenever I write in an input? Angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a boolean variable `isClearShown: boolean = false;` In my TS component, And i want to toggle the Clear div whenever the input is being written. I have used `*ngIf`, and its not working.

This is the code:

The input:

<input type="search" class="search-field" #inputSearch placeholder="Search networks, applications, and more" value="" name="s" title="" />

and the div i want to hide whenever the input is being written:

```
<div (click)="clearSearch()" [hidden]="isClearShown" *ngIf="isClearShown" class="clear">Clear</div>

      <input type="search" class="search-field" #inputSearch placeholder="Search networks, applications, and more" value="" name="s" title="" />
```

Clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code to something like this:

```
<div (click)="clearSearch()" *ngIf="value != ''" class="clear">Clear</div>
<input type="search" class="search-field" #inputSearch placeholder="Search networks, applications, and more" [(value)]="value" name="s" title="" />
```

In TS file :

```
value:string = "";
```

The value variable will contain the current value of the input field. On change of that, your div will automatically enable or disable

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `[hidden]="condition"` and `*ngIf="condition"` in the same `div` is not correct. You should use either of them not both. `*ngIf` expects an opposite condition to `hidden` property which is native to html. `hidden` just masks the element from the UI but it keeps it in the `DOM`. `*ngIf` however removes the element from the `DOM` and it is specific to Angular. With this being said you need to toggle the `boolean` value of the property passed either to `hidden` or `*ngIf`. That can be done but a variety of ways such as:

1-  `(blur)` and `(focus)` in the `input` field

2-   length of string in input field

You have to specify what you are doing so we can point you to the right direction.

I assume you are using a form (whether `reative` or `template-driven`) from `@Angular/forms`.

- Declare a `formGroup` and `formControl` and connect them both in `TS` file and `HTML` file then set your boolean property based on the value of the input control  `*ngIf="inputField.value !== ''"`. Otherwise just do that by accessing the value of the  template reference directly (The one you named  `#inputSearch` with `@ViewChild('inputSearch') inputSearch:ElementRef`) .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example of template reference usage

```
     <input (keyup)="0" type="text" #lastName id="lastName">
     <div *ngIf="lastName.value != ''"> This div will appear when input has content. Here is the content of input: {{lastName.value}}</div>
```